# Adjusting UILabels size (i.e., width and height) inside a UITableViewCell Class?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I created a custom UITableViewCell Class as illustrated below, whereby i defined the items I would like to be displayed inside my custom cell (specifically UILabel items):

```
import UIKit

import ChameleonFramework

class IsectionsCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let sectionDesignationLabelTopPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let sectionDesignationLabelLeftPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let sectionDesignationLabelRightPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let depthOfSectionLabelTopPadding: CGFloat = 0

    let depthOfSectionLabelLeftPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let depthOfSectionLabelRightPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let webThicknessLabelTopPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let webThicknessLabelLeftPadding: CGFloat = 10

    let webThicknessLabelRightPadding: CGFloat = 10

    var sectionDesignationLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        label.textAlignment = .left

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F27E63")

        return label

    }()

    var depthOfSectionLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.textColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F27E63")

        return label

    }()

        override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        addSubview(sectionDesignationLabel)

        addSubview(depthOfSectionLabel)

        applyAppropriateSizeAndConstraintsForCellItems()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

    }

    func applyAppropriateSizeAndConstraintsForCellItems() {

        sectionDesignationLabel.frame.size.width = 200

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            sectionDesignationLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: sectionDesignationLabelLeftPadding),

            sectionDesignationLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -1*sectionDesignationLabelRightPadding),

            sectionDesignationLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: sectionDesignationLabelTopPadding),

            depthOfSectionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sectionDesignationLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: depthOfSectionLabelTopPadding),

            depthOfSectionLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: depthOfSectionLabelLeftPadding),

            depthOfSectionLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -1 * (((self.frame.size.width)/2) + depthOfSectionLabelRightPadding)),

            ])

    }

}
```

As it can be seen from the declaration of depthOfSectionLabel, whereby I stated the width and height of its frame. However, these values are not reflected when my table gets displayed (please refer to attached image). The width is displayed much more greater than the 50 I specified for this specific label?

My question is how can I adjust the widths of the various labels to be displayed inside my tableView custom Cell?

[image]

Comment: You're setting a constraint for the rightAnchor and have `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to false so the frame is not used. If you want the label width to be 50 then set a width constraint.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but that did not work as well. If I can obtain the width of the custom cell, my problem would be solved, however I cannot achieve this? I tried self.frame.size.width but it seems to return 0 and not the actual width of the custom cell I am looking for

Comment: What is it you’re trying to achieve? How do you want the label to be laid out?